# Error on WPN-XM php7

Tags: php-7, wpn-xm

the systm version is WPNXM-0.8.6-Standard-Setup-php56-w64 . After I intalling php7.0.10_nts and when I change php version appear an error

[problem with php7.0.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb8ma.jpg)

Where is a problem ???

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your php 7 folder (*C:\server\bin\php*) you will find that there are 2 php.ini files:

- php.ini-development
- php.ini-production

If you **copy** one of them with the name **php.ini**. this should fix it.

Edited:

You may need to change paths too like:

```
extension_dir = "ext"y
error_log = C:\server\logs\php_error.log
include_path = ".;C:\server\bin\php\pear" 
upload_tmp_dir = C:\server\temp
;sendmail_path = "C:\server\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i" 
session.save_path = C:\server\temp
curl.cainfo =C:\server\bin\openssl\ca-bundle.crt

[Xdebug]

; activate remote debugging
xdebug.remote_enable   = on
xdebug.remote_handler  = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host     = localhost
xdebug.remote_port     = 9000

; profiler
xdebug.profiler_enable         = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir     = "C:\server\logs" 
xdebug.profiler_output_name    = cachegrind.out.%t.%p

[Zend]
zend_extension=C:\server\bin\php\ext\php_opcache.dll
zend_extension=C:\server\bin\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
```